# I have to read and display gujarati font stored in database

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli, utf-8

```
<?php
    //set charset:utf-8 //for json, is it right way to do it;
    header('Content-Type:application/json; charset:utf8'); 

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','hospital'); 

    $myArray = array();
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tips")) {

        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $myArray[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($myArray);
    }

    $result->close();
    $mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: This question should be improved...

Comment: Format your code. Explain what you are trying to do, show the input, and the desired output. Show what you've done and how it fails

Comment: And whats your question?

Comment: Are you able to read stored data in Gujarati font?

Comment: `SELECT HEX(col), col FROM tips WHERE ...` so we can see what is in the table.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the field's collation to "utf8_bin" so that mysql will store the data in gujarati properly. and also you need a proper gujarati font to apply a css class font-family propery

Comment: thanks i found answer...just set database utf8 format